# Magento2 - I want to show custom quote item field to checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, quoteitem

I want to show custom `quote item` field to **Checkout Page**.

I don't know how would I do that. I've added one custom `drop down` to Cart page and selected value I saved in `quote_item` table now I want that value show in checkout page.

here I attached screenshot[image]

Would be great If someone can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to override two files in your theme. One for adding a header and another for adding the value of that column.

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/form.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// phpcs:disable Magento2.Templates.ThisInTemplate

/**  @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Grid */
?>
<?php $mergedCells = ($this->helper(Magento\Tax\Helper\Data::class)->displayCartBothPrices() ? 2 : 1); ?>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('form_before') ?>
<form action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost')) ?>"
          method="post"
          id="form-validate"
          data-mage-init='{"Magento_Checkout/js/action/update-shopping-cart":
              {"validationURL" : "<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getUrl('checkout/cart/updateItemQty')) ?>",
              "updateCartActionContainer": "#update_cart_action_container"}
          }'
          class="form form-cart">
    <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
    <div class="cart table-wrapper<?= $mergedCells == 2 ? ' detailed' : '' ?>">
        <?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()) :?>
            <div class="cart-products-toolbar cart-products-toolbar-top toolbar"
                 data-attribute="cart-products-toolbar-top"><?= $block->getPagerHtml() ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif ?>
        <table id="shopping-cart-table"
               class="cart items data table"
               data-mage-init='{"shoppingCart":{"emptyCartButton": ".action.clear",
               "updateCartActionContainer": "#update_cart_action_container"}}'>
            <caption class="table-caption"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Shopping Cart Items')) ?></caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="col item" scope="col"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Item')) ?></span></th>
                    <th class="col price" scope="col"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Price')) ?></span></th>
                    <th class="col qty" scope="col"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?></span></th>
                    <th class="col subtotal" scope="col"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Subtotal')) ?></span></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php foreach ($block->getItems() as $_item) :?>
                <?= $block->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </table>
        <?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()) :?>
            <div class="cart-products-toolbar cart-products-toolbar-bottom toolbar"
                 data-attribute="cart-products-toolbar-bottom"><?= $block->getPagerHtml() ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif ?>
    </div>
    <div class="cart main actions">
        <?php if ($block->getContinueShoppingUrl()) :?>
            <a class="action continue"
               href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getContinueShoppingUrl()) ?>"
               title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Continue Shopping')) ?>">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Continue Shopping')) ?></span>
            </a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <button type="button"
                name="update_cart_action"
                data-cart-empty=""
                value="empty_cart"
                title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Clear Shopping Cart')) ?>"
                class="action clear" id="empty_cart_button">
            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Clear Shopping Cart')) ?></span>
        </button>
        <button type="submit"
                name="update_cart_action"
                data-cart-item-update=""
                value="update_qty"
                title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Update Shopping Cart')) ?>"
                class="action update">
            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Update Shopping Cart')) ?></span>
        </button>
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="update_cart_action_container" data-cart-item-update=""/>
    </div>
</form>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('checkout.cart.order.actions') ?>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('shopping.cart.table.after') ?>
```

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/default.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// phpcs:disable Magento2.Templates.ThisInTemplate
// phpcs:disable Magento2.Files.LineLength.MaxExceeded

/** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer */

$_item = $block->getItem();
$product = $_item->getProduct();
$isVisibleProduct = $product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();
/** @var \Magento\Msrp\Helper\Data $helper */
$helper = $this->helper(Magento\Msrp\Helper\Data::class);
$canApplyMsrp = $helper->isShowBeforeOrderConfirm($product) && $helper->isMinimalPriceLessMsrp($product);
?>
<tbody class="cart item">
    <tr class="item-info">
        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Item')) ?>" class="col item">
            <?php if ($block->hasProductUrl()) :?>
                <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl()) ?>"
                   title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getProductName()) ?>"
                   tabindex="-1"
                   class="product-item-photo">
            <?php else :?>
                <span class="product-item-photo">
            <?php endif;?>
            <?= $block->getImage($block->getProductForThumbnail(), 'cart_page_product_thumbnail')->toHtml() ?>
            <?php if ($block->hasProductUrl()) :?>
                </a>
            <?php else :?>
                </span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="product-item-details">
                <strong class="product-item-name">
                    <?php if ($block->hasProductUrl()) :?>
                        <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl()) ?>"><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getProductName()) ?></a>
                    <?php else :?>
                        <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getProductName()) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </strong>
                <?php if ($_options = $block->getOptionList()) :?>
                    <dl class="item-options">
                        <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) :?>
                            <?php $_formatedOptionValue = $block->getFormatedOptionValue($_option) ?>
                            <dt><?= $block->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?></dt>
                            <dd>
                                <?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])) :?>
                                    <?= $block->escapeHtml($_formatedOptionValue['full_view']) ?>
                                <?php else :?>
                                    <?= $block->escapeHtml($_formatedOptionValue['value'], ['span', 'a']) ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </dd>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </dl>
                <?php endif;?>
                <?php if ($messages = $block->getMessages()) :?>
                    <?php foreach ($messages as $message) :?>
                        <div class= "cart item message <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($message['type']) ?>">
                            <div><?= $block->escapeHtml($message['text']) ?></div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php $addInfoBlock = $block->getProductAdditionalInformationBlock(); ?>
                <?php if ($addInfoBlock) :?>
                    <?= $addInfoBlock->setItem($_item)->toHtml() ?>
                <?php endif;?>
            </div>
        </td>

        <?php if ($canApplyMsrp) :?>
            <td class="col msrp" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Price')) ?>">
                <span class="pricing msrp">
                    <span class="msrp notice"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('See price before order confirmation.')) ?></span>
                    <?php $helpLinkId = 'cart-msrp-help-' . $_item->getId(); ?>
                    <a href="#" class="action help map"
                       id="<?= ($block->escapeHtmlAttr($helpLinkId)) ?>"
                       data-mage-init='{"addToCart":{
                                            "helpLinkId": "#<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeHtml($helpLinkId)) ?>",
                                            "productName": "<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeHtml($product->getName())) ?>",
                                            "showAddToCart": false
                                            }
                                        }'
                    >
                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__("What's this?")) ?></span>
                    </a>
                </span>
            </td>
        <?php else :?>
            <td class="col price" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Price')) ?>">
                <?= $block->getUnitPriceHtml($_item) ?>
            </td>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <td class="col qty" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>">
            <div class="field qty">
                <div class="control qty">
                    <label for="cart-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>-qty">
                        <span class="label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?></span>
                        <input id="cart-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>-qty"
                               name="cart[<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>][qty]"
                               data-cart-item-id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getSku()) ?>"
                               value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getQty()) ?>"
                               type="number"
                               size="4"
                               step="any"
                               title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Qty')) ?>"
                               class="input-text qty"
                               data-validate="{required:true,'validate-greater-than-zero':true}"
                               data-role="cart-item-qty"/>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td class="col subtotal" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Subtotal')) ?>">
            <?php if ($canApplyMsrp) :?>
                <span class="cart msrp subtotal">--</span>
            <?php else :?>
                <?= $block->getRowTotalHtml($_item) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item-actions">
        <td colspan="4">
            <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getActions($_item) ?>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Let me know still if you have any query.

Thanks

Comment: i want value in checkout page not on cart page. i've save value from cart to quote_item table and want to display in checkout page.